# i don't have enough points on this SE to do this, but can someone add a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

there should be a tag associated with the ADC and DAC for sigma-delta.

Answer (score 10):

Right now we have [adc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adc) and [dac](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dac), and we do not distinguish between different topologies. I don't see a major benefit to adding this distinction, so I'm not going to add a tag.